# New Infopath 2013 in O 365: Select the form template to open this xml file

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, template, forms-library, office-365

I create a new forms library in o365/SPO. I click new document and it opens InfoPath2013 and asks for

> Select the form template to open this xml file

Where do I get this from?

Also if select New InfoPath 2013 is says *Find a form*

I see no design option, or save as. All the design features are grayed out.

I confirmed I am logged into o365 as my corporate user that is using ADFS.

From InfoPath 2013 if I select NEW I'm only offered *Find a Form*.

How do I create a new Infopath form or template?
Where can I find templates?

It's an A2 Office 365 license and I have owner rights to the library.

Answer (score 1):

You must first have a template.

Apparently it works if you open Infopath and then select the SharePoint list data source and not the other way around.

Comment: Old post but where it says "select the form template to open this xml file" it also says "If you are working with a form library on a SharePoint site, close this dialog box, and then use InfoPath to publish a form template to the library.".